# What is the range attribute of a referent in the genius api?

Tags: genius-api

see: [Genius API Referent](https://docs.genius.com/#!#referents-h2). All I can find is when hovering over the property in an example of the API docs: "Information for anchoring the referent in the source text". **Does anyone know or have a link to docs about it? What structures might it have? Will the format of `range` differ depending on the type of item to which it refers?**

Sometimes it looks like the range is a bit structured (`/referents/10225839`):

```
...
range: {
    start: "/div[1]/p[1]",
    startOffset: "0",
    end: "/div[1]/p[1]",
    endOffset: "76",
    before: "d-color: #fff;
            }
            div {
                width: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-radius: 0;
                padding: 1em;
            }
        }





        Example Domain
        ",
    after: ". You may use this
        domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.
        More information...



    ",
    content: "This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents"
},...
```

while other times it seems less so (`/referents?song_id=3039923`):

```
range: {
    content: "I make a play fucking up your whole life"
},
```

Comment: maybe it has to do with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range ?